# Energy crossing node per second in Partial standing waves

Tags: waves

Consider two waves:
$$y_1 = 5sin(\omega t-kx)$$
$$y_2 = 3sin(\omega t + kx)$$

So, we superimpose them to get:
$$y_1 + y_2 = 3[ sin(\omega t + kx) + \sin (\omega t - kx) ] + 2 \sin(\omega t - kx)$$

The left part refers a pure standing wave and right part is pure travelling wave.

Common argument is that energy through node is $0$ in pure standing wave, and hence energy transfer from node here will be just due to the travelling wave ( and just substituting amplitude as $2$ in the formula of power will give energy transfer p. sec.).

But I highly doubt if doing this is correct and I tried to try proving this wrong by using
$$P = F_{transverse} \cdot \frac{\partial y_{res}}{\partial t}$$
where $y_1 = A_1\sin(\omega t - kx)$, $y_2 = A_2\sin(\omega t+kx)$ and hence $y_{res} = y_1 + y_2$.
$$P = T_0 \left(\frac{\partial y_{1}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y_{}}{\partial x}\right)\left(\frac{\partial y_{1}}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial y_{}}{\partial t}\right)$$
where $T_0$ is the horizontal component of the tension in the wire.

But I am not able to take it further from here and take average to prove or disprove:
$$P_{avg} = \frac{1}{2}\mu (A_1 - A_2)^2 \omega^2 v$$
where $\mu$ is the linear mass density of the rope, $v$ is velocity of wave.

Can someone guide me ahead of this?

Comment: For the travelling part [Energy and Power of a Wave](https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/16-4-energy-and-power-of-a-wave)

Comment: @Farcher yeah I know that derivation, But I was more interested in finding Power for "partial standing wave" from just the equation got by the superposition (by using $F \cdot v$ and then taking average to find the average power) and not using the fact that the energy will just be due to the travelling wave.

Comment: But how is that different from using your $y_1+y_2$ equation and showing the square bracket term average to be zero?